# Cannot connect to Cloud SQL instance - ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I cannot connect to my cloud sql instance since 5-Sep from outside google cloud.

I authorized all networks, tried connecting from gcloud and cloud sql proxy but I am hitting same error every time **ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0**

. Even restarting the instance did not help.

Comment: Please send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with your full instance name and a reference to this post. The Cloud SQL may be able to help with this.

Comment: I had the exact same issue before. not sure what was the resolution as i didn't do anything. I was working on this issue late at night then after like trying everything i decided to continue working on it tomorrow morning and when i wake up, found it working !! so my assumptions it was a problem on Google Team side and @Herman is correct you have to contact google team regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Within hours of my posting the question here , I could connect to mysql instance. Guess it was an issue at google's end.

Thanks @Herman next time if I face the issue again, I will email the cloud-sql (cloud-sql@google.com) team instead of posting it in stack overflow.